# myArray[items].toUpperCase is not a function

Tags: javascript

When i run below code

```
<script>

    var name = "Hello moorthi";
    var myArray = name.split(' ');

    setTimeout(function(){
      var nameDisplay='';
      try {
        for (var names in myArray){

          nameDisplay += myArray[names].toUpperCase()+' ';
        }
        alert(nameDisplay);
      }
      catch(err){
        console.log(err.message);
      }
    },
    1000);

 </script>
```

getting **undefined is not a function** error in chrome, can help me why this happening?

Comment: do not use a for in loop to loop an array.

Comment: can you give me solution on this

Comment: The solution is to stop using a for-in loop.

Comment: The array traversal is irrelevant to the error here.
@user3791235: I can run your code fine here: http://jsfiddle.net/T4xYS/. Is the code you post *actually* the code that you're running?

Comment: Yes  Dancrumb, but it's  going to break... Why?

Comment: What do you mean "it's going to break"?

Comment: Oh... is this a homework question?

Comment: @YungGun And I too make comments on questions from 5 years in the past. And comments are not freaking answers. Sorry I made a statement to not do something that was causing the issues. There are times when I do not have 5 minutes to write an answer so I make a quick statement and hopefully someone that has time makes the answer with the details. That is how I been doing it on stackoverflow for the last 11 years. And the correct answer today would be use map.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure this will guarantee the order of the elements in the array. The best solution would be to go with a for loop (both for performance and order):

```
for (var i=0, len=myArray.length; i<len; i++){
      msgupdate += myArray[i].toUpperCase()+' ';
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Use

```
msgupdate = myArray.map(function (i) { return i.toUpperCase() }).join(' ');
```

Using `for/in` isn't a good idea, without a `hasOwnProperty` check.

Comment: meagar, can you explain more about hasOwnProperty?